# A shorter way to update EntityFramework model from database? (VS2013, EF6)

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

Each time I make a change in the database I have to

Double-click Model1.edmx > Ctrl+A > Delete > Right Click > Update Model from Database > Click next a few times > Mark "Tables" > Finish > Save and close

It takes a long time with the waiting, can I do this any faster somehow, maybe via a script or command? Even better if as a background operation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete objects in entity. Just right click and update. EF will auto detect updates and correct your model. You will need to delete some columns and object from model if you delete them in database, because EF doesn't automatically deletes them from model. But if you add some table or columns then just update your model without deleting any object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but your solution takes even more time due to added deleting process.